# Not able to access Apache HTTP on CentOS server from another machine from the same LAN

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, apache-http-server, centos

I am on CentOS 7.  I started the Apache HTTP server.  I can see the index page by typing the IP address (192.168.1.147 in my case) on the local machine.

If I try this from another machine (Windows 10) on the same wireless network, I get the following:

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.1.147 took too long to respond.
```

I cannot telnet to port 80 on that machine

```
Microsoft Telnet> open 192.168.1.147 80
Connecting To 192.168.1.147...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

However, I can ssh to the IP address from the other machine.

I tried putting the following in the httpd.conf

```
Listen 192.168.1.147:80
```

That did not work either.  I tried disabling/stopping firewalld to no avail.

Nothing seems to be working.  Since ssh on port 22 is accessible, I am thinking somewhere access to port 80 is blocked.

Any idea what else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, when I did the following it worked

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
```

Disabling/stopping 'firewalld' did not seem to help or I may not have done it correctly.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

gives me the following:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp2s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Before I ran the command, http was not listed.

There was no need to change the httpd.conf file

To get it to work for both http and https, the following can be run

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```